# Reinstall grub on a different drive?

Tags: arch-linux, boot, grub, boot-loader

I dismantled my PC & reassembled it, after that GRUB disappeared.
I have two disks: a SSD (sdb, GPT) and a HDD (sda, MBR):

- sda1: "part" (128MB)
- sda2: windows, ntfs
- sda3: windows again, ntfs (added this partition after installing grub & arch)
- sda4: arch linux /
- sdb1: windows's recovery (ntfs)
- sdb2: /boot/efi (vfat)
- sdb3: "part" again, 16MB
- sdb4: windows again (main windows partition, it is installed here)

I usually booted on my SSD, and I had windows boot loader & arch_grub
Now I only have windows boot loader, but grub's files are still there, there's `grubx64.efi` in `/boot/efi/EFI/arch_grub`, and `grubenv`, `grub.cfg`, `x86_64-efi` in `/boot`
(I installed windows in UEFI mode, and I guess I installed arch too in UEFI mode, I used architect)

So basically grub is in `/boot` which is on my HDD (and `/boot/efi` is on my SSD), everything worked fine until now. I tried to use `boot-repair` on an ubuntu live usb, but I had the error "arch does not have `grub-amd64-efi-signed` package installed"

I think I can still boot on arch with [grub's command line](https://www.linux.com/learn/how-rescue-non-booting-grub-2-Linux) but what will I do then ? I already have every needed files, therefore [grub-install](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#Installation_2) will be useless

Comment: if you can get arch to boot at all via the grub command line, you should be able to run `update-grub` and it will re-generate the `grub.cfg` to match the current drive setup.  You may also need to run `efibootmgr` again so that it also matches the new drive layout.  You're runing Arch, so see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB/EFI_examples

Comment: Sorry but I'm lost, I can't find a manual page for `efibootmgr`, so I don't know which arguments I have to enter. Also, I have a MSI B250M Pro-VDH, and every single file of grub is okay, so if I replace the `bootx64.efi` by `grubx64.efi`, it will boot directly on grub ? Is that a bad idea ?

Comment: Nevermind, found a manual page. If I redo grub config & add a boot entry with `efibootmgr`, will it be okay ? https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#efibootmgr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Raman Sailopal and cas for the help, but it didn't fit my case.
Here are the exact steps to follow, assuming /dev/sda4 is linux root, /dev/sdb2 is your EFI partition (located in /boot/efi), and your linux/initrd files are `/boot/vmlinuz-linux` & `/boot/initramfs.img`
Burn a live usb of ubuntu (16.04?) with amd64 architecture, boot on it and paste these commands:

```
sudo os-prober
efibootmgr
```

Install os-prober or efibootmgr if it isn't installed yet:

```
sudo apt-get install os-prober
sudo apt-get install efibootmgr
```

Grub in efi mode is probably not installed, install it too

```
sudo apt-get install grub-efi-amd64-signed
```

Then, install grub:

```
sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sda4 /mnt
sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sdb2 /mnt/boot/efi
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/mnt/boot/efi --boot-directory=/mnt/boot --bootloader-id=grub
```

Don't try to use `grub-mkconfig`, it will not work.
Instead, boot from your newly grub bootloader, [you will have a grub shell, paste these commands](https://www.linux.com/learn/how-rescue-non-booting-grub-2-Linux):

```
set root=(hd0,4)
linux /boot/vmlinuz-linux root=/dev/sda4
initrd /boot/initramfs.img
boot
```

After that, you should be on linux, mount your efi partition if it's not already, install grub/os-prober/efibootmgr, and run these:

```
sudo os-prober
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi --boot-directory=/boot --bootloader-id=grub
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Reboot, and grub is back.

Answer (score 0):

Boot off a Linux recovery media/live CD and then mount /dev/sda4 to /mnt and /dev/sdb2 to /mnt/boot. chroot /mnt and then run grub-install /dev/sdb.

Comment: `grub-install` may install grub files to another folder, they will be redundant. If I just regenerate grub's config & use `efibootmgr` as cas said, it will work I guess ?

Comment: I have tried that: https://www.pastiebin.com/5981bee6233ec your answer doesn't work with efi and for my case

Comment: Shouldn't grub-mkconfig -o be to /mnt/boot and not /boot?

Comment: When i executed grub-mkconfig I was already on arch (said it in the comments)